# Python: sys.path.append vs. import?

Tags: python, ironpython, python-import

I have a (single) .py script. In it, I need to import a library.

In order for this library to be found, I need to call sys.path.append. However, I do not want to hardcode the path to the library, but pass it as a parameter.

So my problem is that if I make a function (set_path) in this file, I need to import the file, and import fails because the path is not yet appended.

What are good ways to solve this problem?

Clarification after comments:

- I am using IronPython, and the library path is the path to CPython/lib. This path is (potentially) different on every system.
- As far as I know, I cannot pass anything via sys.argv, because the script is run in an embedded python interpreter, and there is no main function.

Comment: Is the library not stored with your Python install (in site-packages)?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable instead of changing `sys.path`?

Comment: I am using IronPython, and need to use CPython packages; the path I want to append is actually the path to the CPython lib dir. So no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe pass the file as an argument using sys.argv, add it to the path and then import it.
Then run your program like this:

```
python my_program.py somefolder/some_import.py
```

Here's a reference for using sys.argv: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/python-sys-argv/

Answer (score 3):

You should not do the import globally, but inside a function which gets called after you appended the path.